# How to validate HTML/CSS files with grunt.js?

Tags: validation, gruntjs

I would like to use grunt.js as a build tool for my web project. Can I use grunt.js to validate my HTML/CSS files? Do you have an example of such a grunt.js file?

Answer (score 7):

There is another plugin that seems to be updated more often and does not require java. [grunt-html-validation](https://github.com/praveenvijayan/grunt-html-validation).  It has a number of options and has been working great for me.  You can install and use it like this:

```
npm install grunt-html-validation --save-dev
```

Then put something like this in the initconfig of your Gruntfile.js

and this in appropriate places in your Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html-validation');
grunt.registerTask("default", ["validation"]);
```

There is also a number of useful options including the ability to relax errors based on a regular expression (could be useful for AngularJS for example) and the ability to save a report.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the grunt plugin [grunt-html](https://github.com/jzaefferer/grunt-html). Beware, you will need Java on your computer to use it. It works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

As of now there seem to be two popular HTML validation plugins:

- [grunt-html-validation](https://github.com/praveenvijayan/grunt-html-validation)
- [grunt-html](https://github.com/jzaefferer/grunt-html)

`grunt-html-validation` uses the W3C Markup Validation Service and `grunt-html` uses a local copy of the java-based The Nu HTML Checker.

They both work well and have very similar options so it comes down to whether you want to wait for an external service call or wait for a local java app.